# Ubuntu 16.04 connected to WiFi, no Internet

Tags: networking, 16.04

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 over the weekend. My family had to reconfigure our gateway and router setup since then, and in so doing I lost all Internet connection on my computer.

Everyone else's devices in the house have Internet connection (there are over eight other devices), including my iPad and my PlayStation. All work except for my computer.

I've experienced this before with earlier Ubuntu versions. Always when someone changes a setting on or power cycles our gateway or router.

I've since looked up countless solutions on here, but none of them are working or giving me any leads.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot my Internet issue?

Comment: You need to describe your hardware and what you have tried so far

Comment: @AmiasChanner Hi, thank you for responding. Sorry, my web page on my tablet just refreshed itself when I switched tabs and I lost everything I wrote. I think I'll write it in parts.

Comment: @AmiasChanner My network controller in lspci is the Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express). I bought it specifically to work with Linux from a Linux-friendly retailer less than a year ago. It works great normally. Our router is an Apple Airport Express, and we also have an Apple Repeater set up to extend range across our house. Our gateway is a Pace 5168N issued standard from our ISP.

Comment: @AmiasChanner So, things I have tried.  Renewing DHCP lease with "nmcli c down id 'Brak 1'" and "nmcli c up id 'Brak 1'".  Flushing the DNS cache with "sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean restart".  Ignoring and disabling iPv6 temporarily with "sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp2s0/disable_ipv6'".  Clearing more firewall settings I think with "sudo iptables -F".

Comment: @AmiasChanner Generally, I've tried forgetting the network several times, disabling wireless, disabling networking, rebooting my computer, and reconnecting to the network several times. It almost always reconnects to the router and gives me an IP address, but I'm unable to get to any web pages or access anything online.

Comment: @AmiasChanner One weird thing is when a try to ping my router with "ping 10.0.1.1", I get "From 10.0.1.15 icmp_seq=12 Destination Host Unreachable", and it keeps outputting subsequent icmp_seq attempts infinitely, and I have to quit Terminal to stop it.

Comment: what does it actually say when you try to connect with it ?

Comment: @AmiasChanner Well, it connects automatically now when I start up my computer and log into Ubuntu. In the top panel where the Internet connection is, it shows I am connected to 'Brak' (our router) with two out of four bars. Would you like to know all of my information listed in Connection Information?

Comment: @AmiasChanner What I meant was I get a successful WiFi connection to my router on startup, but still no Internet. Just to be clear.

Comment: the next thing to check would be to run   'route -n'  and 'ifconfig' post the results here.  This will show us how the adapter is configured and where its expecting to find the route to the internet.

Comment: @AmiasChanner Alright, here is 'route -n'. Sorry for my lack of formatting, I'm on a tablet and not very technical. "Kernel IP routing table. <br />Destination, Gateway, Genmask, Flags, Metric, Ref, Use, Iface. <br />0.0.0.0, 10.0.1.1, 0.0.0.0, UG, 600, 0, 0, wlp2s0. <br />10.0.1.0, 0.0.0.0, 255.255.255.0, U, 600, 0, 0, wlp2s0. <br />169.254.0.0, 0.0.0.0, 255.255.0.0, U, 1000, 0, 0, wlp2s0"

Comment: @AmiasChanner And here is 'ifconfig'. I'll just transcribe what it says for the 'wlp2s0' device, since it takes a long time to type on here. Let me know if you need the others. "wlp2s0, Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:22:43:4c:ad:48 inet addr:10.0.1.15 Bcast:10.0.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 inet6 addr: fe80::9f4e:5039:d428:b535/64 Scope:Link UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST. MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:14846 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:3476 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:3203529 (3.2 MB). TX bytes:423582 (423.5 KB)"

Comment: 14846 errors is not good , there must be something in the logs about this try running 'journalctl -f'  and then get networkmanager to reconnect. I think your WPA supplicant might not working right so no packets get sent. Everything else looks ok.  
 
Given that your connection appears to be a straightforward DHCP connection i would try making a new connection profile for it in networkmanager just to rule out corruption of the old one.

Comment: @AmiasChanner I believe it is 'RX packets:14846' and 'errors:0'. Sorry for the jumbled output.

Comment: @AmiasChanner I'm trying to create a new connection profile (have never done it before), but when I try to connect using it, it tries forever but eventually fails. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @AmiasChanner Just wondering why my new connection profile won't connect to my router. I named it 'Brak 2', and made all of the settings the same as 'Brak 1'. It tries but it won't connect. Do I need to delete the old profile for it to work, or do something else?

Comment: Can anybody help me resolve my Internet issue?